# Dynamic account creation

Tags: docusignapi

While creating an account and API keys via your website is fine for a tech person, what I would like to do is automate that portion of the process.  Our system can cretae client instamces fairly easily and it would be useful if the client can connect to DocuSign without having to visit your site or having us teach them how to go about setting it up.

Is this possible?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

It would be helpful of your question included more information on your use case--what are you trying to accomplish?

If you are an ISV who wants multiple DocuSign customers to integrate their accounts with your product then the DocuSign customers do **NOT** (and should not) create integration keys (client_ids).

This is because the integration key you create for your software product can be used by any user on any DocuSign account (via your product).

An integration key is per custom API Application (integration). So only developers create them.

If your goal is to programmatically create User ids or Accounts, you can do both--ask another question if you have difficulties.

**Updated**

The original poster has clarified his question: In some DocuSign examples, [Legacy Authentication](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/guide/authentication/legacy_auth.html) code examples show how to create the Legacy Authentication header by combining an email, password, and integration key.

Does the integration key belong to the email/password (the end user)? Ie does an end user need to create an integration key?

Answer:

No. An integration key can be used with any email/pw combination from any account. An ISV should create one integration key for each of their applications. Then, any of the ISV's customers, using any DocuSign account, will be able to use the ISV's application.

If Legacy Authentication is used, then the app must request an email/pw from the end customer.

***But don't use Legacy Authentication!!***

Instead, use OAuth for either [ISV Service Integrations](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/guide/authentication/oa2_jwt.html) or [ISV User Applications](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/guide/authentication/oa2_auth_code.html). OAuth is modern, more secure, and easy to use. Please do not build new apps using Legacy Authentication. Thank you.

Comment: My apologies for not being clear.  The use case is that of an ISV with multiple DocuSign clients and the code that I am working with is: 
var  email = "***",    // your account email
     password = "***",   // your account password
integratorKey = "***", // your Integrator Key (found on the Preferences -> API page)  
taken from https://github.com/docusign/docusign-rest-recipes/blob/master/request_sig_via_email/request_sig_via_email.js  
In the code above "your email" and "your password" are from the client's settings and the "integrator key" is my API key.  Correct?

Comment: My apologies for the formatting, I cannot get the text to look properly, even after RTFM